# MySQL UNION, order by datetime from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

////EDIT

To people who could be strugeling with long and complex MySQL request, please try it in PhpmyAdmin! It will tell you the error!

////EDIT

Each table (table1 & table2) has their own DATETIME field.
I'm trying to catch id's of the two tables and order them by their DATETIME field.

Example:

```
Table 1                        Table 2
------------                 -------------
id |  datetime1               id | table1id  | datetime2
------------------------      -----------------------
1  |  2014-09-21 20:31:26     1  | 2         | 2014-09-21 20:31:29
2  |  2014-09-21 20:31:27     2  | 3         | 2014-09-21 20:31:30
3  |  2014-09-21 20:31:28

Table 3                      
------------               
id |  user               
------------------------   
2  |  phil                
3  |  nathalie
```

My output isn't ordered properly with this try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
    1 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    2 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id
) AS query
ORDER BY table1.datetime1 DESC, table2.datetime2 DESC
```

Desired data:
from table 2 id: 2, 1,
from table 1 id: 3, 2, 1
So: 2, 1, 3, 2, 1

Comment: What was the point of the edit, after it was already closed as a dupe of your prior question? If you want to update the question, please edit the original question rather than re-posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
1 AS selection, 
table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
table2.datetime2 
table3.user 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.table1id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
ON table1.id = table3.id
ORDER BY table2.datetime2 DESC 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
2 AS selection, 
table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
table2.datetime2 
table3.user 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.table1id
INNER JOIN table3
ON table1.id = table3.id
ORDER BY table1.datetime1 DESC
```

The ORDER BY needs to be on each query with just a UNION between them.

Comment: MySQL does not accept this ORDER BY in each query... Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: What do you mean "does not accept"? You're running two separate queries and just applying UNION to the result.

Comment: I also placed this answer on your original question.

Comment: Well, it missed `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... ) `

Comment: You don't want to use a subquery here - it over complicates what you're trying to accomplish. Your results can be gotten without the additional overhead.

Comment: Like I said to answear below: This works, but when I add a id on table1 without id on table2 (like first id in table1) output is: 2.2, 2.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1 and should be 1.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1 (That's why I duplicated the question...)

Comment: Can you setup a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d2a4/8

Comment: updating my answer on your other post.

Comment: Based on the comment that you made above your first question does not clearly describe the outcome that you desire. Are you expecting the entire order to take into account both tables dates?

Comment: yes. Output has to be ordered by the 2 dates columns as they where only one column.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give each subquery its own order by clause:

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
    SELECT 
    1 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id
    ORDER BY table1.datetime1 DESC
   )t1

  UNION ALL SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    2 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id
    ORDER BY table2.datetime2 DESC
    ) t2
```

**EDIT**
so in that case you should put all the datetimes in a single column and order by in the outer clause

```
        SELECT *
 FROM (
    SELECT 
    1 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1 as dtime, 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id
   )t1

  UNION ALL SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    2 AS selection, 
    table1.id,
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id
    ) t2

    ORDER BY dtime DESC
```

Comment: This works, but when I add a id on table1 without id on table2 (like first id in table1) output is: 2.2, 2.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1 and should be 1.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1

Comment: So you mean it's not possible to have desired output with 2 datetime fields in 2 tables?

Comment: well, I guess you could, so in the first subquery it'd be `select dt1 as columnToOrderBy,dt1,dt2` and in the second `select dt2 as columnToOrderBy,dt1,dt2` then order by `columnToOrderBy` in the outer query

Comment: No, it's possible. You just have to have a different approach.

Comment: Please see the updated answer on your original question - change the datetime columns in each table and you can do this easily.